# Developing on Windows

Tags: windows

OK. So I know there is Visual Basic and C#, and I am currently in a class for C# now. But say that I want to develop a 3D game? What language, platform and tools would I be using? What about an Internet Browser? Would it be the same?

I guess what I'm asking is how do people such as at Google or Blizzard, develop their software for Windows? Do they end up having to do something drastically different for OSX? I know their probably isn't just one way to do it, but is there a common way?

Comment: Most of those applications you mention are written in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 3D game using C# or VB / .NET platform I'd go for the Microsoft XNA. Since you are in school you can download it for free @ www.dreamspark.com, you just have to have a .edu address and you can get a wealth of resources from that site including Visual Studio Pro 2008, 2010 and XNA Game Studio.

Another good platform is OGRE. OGRE is in C++, but also has a port to C# as well.

People like Google/Blizzard probably use common or heavily customized 3D runtime engines and build off of it. Typically they are using the engine in collaboration with a 3D Graphics Suite such as 3DS Max or Lightwave Studio or even Final Cut Pro or Maya 3D. All except Final Cut are available on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I would start at looking at XNA development with DirectX for windows games  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791

here is some info on wikipedia also  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally the answer is C++ and indeed current browsers and AAA title games (multi-million $$ ones from the big game makers) are most likely going to be in C++

The reason for that is mostly a mix of historical and performance reasons.

For browsers, if you haven't worked on and understand how existing ones work, it's not something you want to tackle.

C# with the XNA framework is a fine starting point for getting into making games (2D or 3D) and there's plenty of tutorials out there.

In general if you're primarily targeting Windows then at the moment C# is probably your best bet.  There's Mono that will let you run your C# programs in Linux and OSX as long as you don't use any Windows specific features (or have a way to exclude them or fall back on something else)

Realistically speaking though for 95% of cases you'll be fine with language you want to develop in, as most of them have support on the 3 main platforms.  When you get more experience in different languages then you can start making judgements on what's more appropriate for your specific project, but when you're first starting out, the most important thing is just learning to get something working.